# After javascript minification Microsoft Edge says "This website needs Internet Explorer"

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge

I'm developing an Angular 2 application and when I leave all the JavaScript files un-minified the site will run (mostly) in Microsoft Edge.  However, after I minify/uglify the code, Edge will tell me that the site needs Internet Explorer.  What about the minification/uglification process is causing this?

The site doesn't use Active-X or Silverlight or anything like that.  I also have the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

Comment: "Microsoft Edge browser in Windows 10 doe not support ActiveX, Silverlight, Java, JavaScript or some other legacy technology" ... OMG

Comment: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/edge-displays-this-website-needs-internet-explorer-message

Comment: @Pietro I've seen that page already and I said in my question that I don't have any of those legacy technologies being used.  JavaScript is obviously supported by Edge and the app (mostly) works when the files are not minified (I do not get the message when not minified)

Comment: I'm an engineer on the Edge team: How are you minifying the code? Have you tried generating an AST of the minified and unminified code to see if the structure changes? Which version of Edge are you using, and is the URL itself accessible online?

Comment: It was not a solution, nor a critic. I checked out the page about that error and found that, I just got suprised. I'm sure @Sampson will be much of help :) apologize for the distraction :O

Comment: @Sampson I'm creating two JS bundles.  One is created by using browserify to discover and concatenate all of the app dependencies and then uglifyjs is used to minify the file.  A second gulp task concatenates the the files specified explicitly in the index html file (scripts like jquery, bootstrap, systemJS, reflectJS, etc.). This second task also uses uglifyJS, via the gulp-uglify plugin, to minifiy the bundled file.  Unfortunately, the site is not available publicly.

Comment: @HisDivineShadow What is the size when compressed, and uncompressed? I'd be curious to see what the code (before and after) looks like as an abstract syntax tree.

Comment: @Sampson The browserified bundle is 4MB uncompressed and 1.6MB compressed.  The other bundle is 965KB and 565KB compressed.  I tried running the site with the unminified bundles to see if that would work but got the same behavior.  The only time is works is when the app is unbundled and loads all the files individually, all 486 (and counting) of them.

Comment: @HisDivineShadow Without access, or more information, I don't think I will be able to assist much further. Do you see the issue only on some pages, and not others? If so, I'd try to work through the process of deduction to determine where the problem code lies.

Comment: @Sampson It's not just on a select pages, as soon as I hit the site, Edge shows the message that it needs to use IE.  If I click the link to "Keep going in Edge" it eventually says "Hmm, we we can't reach this page".  Since I'd really like to find out why this isn't working, let me know how I can get you the site code and I'll send it.

Comment: @HisDivineShadow You may email details to josamp@microsoft.com.

Comment: Is the `mangle` option turned on on your minification tool? That can mess things up. Try setting it to `false`.